# How to get text nodes in order using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to get text nodes and element nodes under 'fomula' element in order, to transform XML into HTML.
I show the XML code below. Texts are not fixed. (I wrote the code in more detail again.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <section>
        <formula>
            m=12n
            <superscript>
                2
            </superscript>
            +3(3n
            <superscript>
                2
            </superscript>
            +2)
        </formula>
        <xxx>
            abc
        </xxx>
        <formula>
            c=a+b
            <superscript>
                4
            </superscript>
        </formula>
    </section>
</root>
```

What should I write XSL to get the result below?

```
<p>m=12n<span>2</span>+3(3n<span>2</span>+2</p>
<p>abc</p>
<p>c=a+b<span>4</span></p>
```

I usually write XSL like below when I get specific element nodes. But I don't know how to get text nodes with sibling element nodes in order.
Please give me advices. (I wrote the code in more detail again.)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        --omitted--
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/section" />
        </body>
    <html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="section">
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
        <xsl:if test="name()='formula'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="name()='xxx'">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="formula">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xxx">
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you write `test="name()='aaa'"`, this is the same as `test=aaa`, no need to get the string value of the name. But better yet, as shown in the answer, do not use these kinds of `xsl:if` constructs with nodes, they will clutter your code and are unnecessary. Simply use `xsl:apply-templates` (see also answer by Rubens), which only has effect if a matching node is found.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm glad to know the simple way to use "test". But I'm still confused. I'm glad, if you check my rewritten code.

Comment: Your `xsl:for-each` will go over all children and your `xsl:if` applies only the children `fomula` and `xxx` (and still test by `name() = 'nodename'`, which is equal to just `nodename`). You can replace the whole `xsl:for-each` and its contents by a single `<xsl:apply-templates select="formula | xxx" />`, which has exactly the same effect as what you have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look into `xsl:template` and `xsl:apply-templates`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/section"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="formula | xxx">
      <p>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </p>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="superscript">
      <span>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
      </span>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can see a [working example here](http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNq).

**EDIT**: a possible approach is to create a template for every specific format you need. So:

- "every time I find a `formula` or a `xxx` element, I shall enclose it's content in a `p` element"
- "every time I find a `superscript` element, I shall enclose it's content in a `span` element"

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Should I need to prepare the template for "formula" and "superscript"? e.g.) <xsl:template match="formula">

Comment: In my example I used those templates to make easier to format specific tags in your xslt output; what else do you need to do here?

Comment: I'm sorry. I might misunderstand your previous answer. I'm little confused and I rewrite the code in more detail. I'm glad, if you give me your advice again.